# Node.js: Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm simply trying to do relational operation with node.js.

**Order Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

**Product Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        defaılt: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

**Route:**

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const order = new Order({
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        product: res.body.productId
    });
    

});
```

**Output:**

{ productId: '5ef31d158399ee48139f330f' }
TypeError: Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const order = new Order({
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        product: req.body.productId
    });
    

});
```

Its req.body.productId not res.body.productId.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your code

`res.body.productId` change it to `req.body.productId`

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body);
 const order = new Order({
     quantity: req.body.quantity,
     //you use response instead of request
     product: res.body.productId
 });
});
```